# getting Error: non-static method 'getResources()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an rpg game on Android studio using Java, and I have png pictures in the Drawable in Resource Manager. I'm trying to convert the drawable to bitmap, but I got the error.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class Player implements GameObject{
    private int direction;
    private boolean move;

    public Player(int direction, boolean move){//constructior
        this.direction = direction;
        this.move = move;

        Drawable myDrawable = MainActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.down_standing);
        Bitmap downStanding      = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){

    }

    @Override
    public void update(){

    }

    public void update(int direction, boolean move){
        this.direction = direction;
        this.move = move;
    }
}
```

as for the MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
        Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels;

        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `getResources()` you'd have a `Context` reference, you can't call it statically, so this is wrong:

```
MainActivity.getResources()
```

To achieve it, you should provide a `Context` parameter, which you can obtain from an Activity:

```
public Player(int direction, boolean move, Context context){  //constructior with Context
    this.direction = direction;
    this.move = move;

    Drawable myDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.down_standing);  // This is right
    Bitmap downStanding = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
}
```